# Checking a range of vector positions in if condition in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like your help with an issue which I guess it's very basic but I can't find something relative or perhaps I don't use the right keywords. So, here it is.

I have vector with zeros and ones and I'm looking for a way to detect the first position with one after 6 positions with zero. For this I have a for loop for parsing the vector and an if with 7 conditions for checking the current position and the 6 places before this. My code is:

```
QVector<int> myV(300);
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    myV[i]=0;
}
for (int i=100; i<120; i++){
    myV[i]=1;
}
for (int i=120; i<300; i++){
    myV[i]=0;
}

for (int i=0; i<myV.size(); i++)
{

    if (myV[i]==1 && myV[i-1]==0 && myV[i-2]==0 && myV[i-3]==0 && 
        myV[i-4]==0 && myV[i-5]==0 && myV[i-6]==0)
    {
       cout << i << " " << myV[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is another better way for doing this, but I can't think of something. The code is in Qt/c++.

Please any ideas would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the code work as intended? If so it belongs on code review stack exchange. If not- what is your specific question?

Comment: Do you have to use a type from Qt and do you have to have a vector?  `std::string` and its `find` would do this really well.  `std::string data = "0101000100..."; auto pos = data.find("1000000");`

Comment: The code you pasted is incomplete.

Comment: @AdamS In it's current form, it's absolutely off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @Mast I don't know the "form" required on there- but it seems like a better place for questions like "please look at my code and tell me how I did- is there a better way of writing it?".

Comment: @AdamS If you don't know the site, don't recommend it. Luckily, there's a couple of guides [(1)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/52915), [(2)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/1014587) available.

Comment: @Mast 5 sec of clicking your first link and it clearly says code review is for open ended questions whereas stack overflow is for specific questions so I don't know what you are on about. There is no question anywhere in this post other than "Can I do this better" Its up to OP to reformat their question to better fit a different community.

Comment: @AdamS Read the rest. This question lacks the context required for a CR question.

Comment: @Mast OP can add context if they wish to post over there, since posts on this site do not require full context.

Comment: CR is for working code, this code is clearly buggy. The last loop has undefined behavior on the first 6 iterations, since it accesses outside the vector (unless `QVector` has well-defined behavior in those cases).

Comment: The question says you're supposed to find the *first* position that meets the conditions. If so, you need to break out of the loop when the condition succeeds, otherwise it will keep going and print other positions that meet the conditions.

Comment: The `if` statement with 7 conditions could be replaced with a loop.

Comment: Bugs can exist in working code. If you read my original question- I say they should post it there *if it is working*

Comment: After `for (int i=0;` any use of `myV[i-anything]` will be out of range if `anything` is above zero.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for spending your time to see my question and deal with it. Actually this is the full code, I have inside the main. What I'm trying to find is to replace the 6 conditions "myV[i-1]==0 && myV[i-2]==0 && myV[i-3]==0 && myV[i-4]==0 && myV[i-5]==0 && myV[i-6]==0" with something else, shorter and nicer. The purpose is as I wrote to detect the position of the 1 after 6 places with zero. Unfortunately I'm really inexperienced in c++ programming, that's why I'm asking you for any better advice.

Answer (score 0):

With std, you may do

```
const std::vector<int> v = {...};
const std::vector<int> sub = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

auto it = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end());
if (it != v.end()) {
     std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), it) << std::endl;
}
```

In C++20, you may even do (or use other Searcher).

```
auto it = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                      std::boyer_moore_searcher(sub.begin(), sub.end()));
```